# Prevent autocomplete for title when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, asking-questions, title

I saw something weird today.

When I started typing a question on Stack Overflow I got an autocomplete pop up suggesting questions I have already asked!

I think this is bad, as those questions are already on the site and if submitted, it would be a duplicate.

It is also unnecessary, so I think it should be removed.

For me it's in Internet Explorer 9, but comments show this is the same in other browsers.
Here is a screenshot:

[image: Example]

Comment: I think browser-provided autocomplete is generally unnecessary, and it's one of the first things I disable when I use a browser for the first time.

Comment: Related: [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form) As an aside: my Chrome does not limit the history to titles I asked myself, but also shows those I edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site does suggest answers with the same or similar titles:

[image]

But, what you are seeing is your browser's auto-complete kicking in.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by your browser's autocomplete feature, not by Stack Overflow. In other words, it's a client-side problem rather than a server-side problem. Disable form autocompletion in your browser if you don't want it.

Comment: I believe it is chrome - it has that draggable corner.

Comment: Yup, I have the same thing in Chrome on my Mac.

Comment: @Lix Note, however, that the OP said "When I started typing a question on Stack Overflow on *IE9"*...

Comment: *slap on the wrist* - "read the question carefully" - note taken.

Comment: absolution! hehe...